# PHP MySQL User registration form doesn't block empty password fields

Tags: php, html, mysql, registration

I'm trying to create a simple user registration form using PHP and MySQL. Everything is working fine except the message "Please insert a password." is never echoed if the password input fields are empty and the data is inserted into the database with a blank password. How can I fix this?

```
<?php
    if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){
        header("Location: index.php");
    }

    if(isset($_POST['register'])){
        include_once('connect.php');

        $name = $surname = $email = $username = "";

        $name = strip_tags($_POST['name']);
        $surname = strip_tags($_POST['surname']);
        $email = strip_tags($_POST['email']);
        $username = strip_tags($_POST['username']);
        $password = strip_tags($_POST['password']);
        $password_confirm = strip_tags($_POST['password_confirm']);

        $name = stripslashes($name);
        $surname = stripslashes($surname);
        $email = stripslashes($email);
        $username = stripslashes($username);
        $password = stripslashes($password);
        $password_confirm = stripslashes($password_confirm);

        $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $name);
        $surname = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $surname);
        $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $email);
        $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $username);
        $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $password);
        $password_confirm = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $password_confirm);

        $password = md5($password);
        $password_confirm = md5($password_confirm);

        $sql_store = "insert into user (username, name, surname, email, password) values ('$username', '$name', '$surname', '$email', '$password')";
        $sql_fetch_username = "select username from user where username = '$username'";
        $sql_fetch_email = "select email from user where email = '$email'";

        $query_username = mysqli_query($conn, $sql_fetch_username);
        $query_email = mysqli_query($conn, $sql_fetch_email);

        if (!empty($name) && !empty($surname) && !empty($email) && !empty($username) && !empty($password) && !empty($password_confirm)){

            if(mysqli_num_rows($query_username)){
                echo "That username is already in use.<br>";
            }

            else{
                if(mysqli_num_rows($query_email)){
                    echo "That email is already in use.<br>";
                }

                else{
                    if($password != $password_confirm){
                        echo "The passwords do not match.<br>";
                    }

                    else{
                        mysqli_query($conn, $sql_store);
                        header("Location: index.php");
                    }                   
                }
            }
        }

        else{           
            if($name == ""){
                echo "Please insert a name.<br>";
            }

            if($surname == ""){
                echo "Please insert a surname.<br>";
            }

            if(mysqli_num_rows($query_username)){
                echo "That username is already in use.<br>";
            }

            if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
                if($email == ""){
                    echo "Please insert an email.<br>";
                }

                else{
                    echo "The email is not valid.<br>";                 
                }
            }

            if(mysqli_num_rows($query_email)){
                echo "That email is already in use.<br>";
            }           

            if($username == ""){
                echo "Please insert an username.<br>";
            }

            if($password == "" || $password_confirm == ""){
                echo "Please insert a password.<br>";
            }
        }
    }
?>

<html>
<body>
    <form action="register.php" method="POST">
        <input placeholder="Name" name="name" type="text" value="<?php if(!empty($name)){echo $name;}?>">
        <input placeholder="Surname" name="surname" type="text" value="<?php if(!empty($surname)){echo $surname;} ?>"><br><br>
        <input placeholder="E-Mail Address" name="email" type="text" value="<?php if(!empty($email)){echo $email;} ?>">
        <input placeholder="Username" name="username" type="text" value="<?php if(!empty($username)){echo $username;} ?>"><br><br>
        <input placeholder="Password" name="password" type="password">
        <input placeholder="Confirm Password" name="password_confirm" type="password">
        <input name="register" type="submit" value="Register">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you also shouldn't use this code if you intend on going live, it's unsafe. Use a prepared statement and `password_hash()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not testing the password, you're testing the md5 hash of the password. The md5 hash of an empty string is not empty.

Also --

Your error message echo-ing is outside of the `<html>` element, which is not ideal. You should set a validation message (or better - a series of validation messages for each input, perhaps in an array) and then output this inside the `<body>` element.

And if this is to be a remotely secure system you should read up on secure password hashing.